# 2d Array to a function expecting int** array as parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I want to use a function made for dynamic arrys for an pre-initialised array too.

```
int MinInRow(int** fieldArray, int value, int currentColumn, int maxNumColumns)
{
    int minVal = 0;
    for (int inkrCol = 0; inkrCol < maxNumColumns; inkrCol++)
    {
        if (feldArray[currentColumn][inkrSpalte] < value)
        {
            minVal = feldArray[currentColumn][inkrCol];
        }
    }
    return minVal;
}
```

So if I try

```
    int testArray[3][4] = 
    { {4,5,6,7}, 
      {0,1,2,3}, 
      {9,8,10,11}, };

    int (*bufferArray)[4] = testArray;
or...
    int** bufferArray = testArray;
or...
    ...

int main()
{
/*
read in other needed parameters
....
*/
std::cout << MinInRow((*bufferArray)[4], int value, int currentColumn, int maxNumColumns);
retrun 0;
}
```

I cant compile. But shouldnt  `int** bufferArray = testarray;` just work fine? I mean there is always an double pointer to the first address of an 2D-Array.

how can I hand it over to the MinInRow-function? Thanks!

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays. In particular, a pointer to an array is not a pointer to a pointer, and can't be converted into one.

Comment: The pseudo-equivalence of arrays and pointers (they are different things, but can be used *as if* they are equivalent in some *contexts*) is only for 1D arrays.    It does not extend to higher dimensions.   So a 2D array can be treated *as if* it is a pointer to a 1D array (with number of elements fixed at compile time) but not as if it is equivalent to a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Just because `T[N]` can beconverted to `T*` does not mean that `T[N][M]` can be converted to `T**`. Instead `T[N][M]` can be converted to `T(*)[M]` which is something completely different.

Comment: Thanks for your advises. I know all these things but of testArray so I can hand it over to the MinInRow function?

Comment: @Lmabda3388 No there is not.

Comment: @Lmabda3388 Perhaps you should consider using `std::vector` instead? Arrays are very awkward to use, vectors are easier.

Comment: Yes probably I should. I am just trying to make ground based things by myselfe to improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little problem. "*" That one tell you that you want to make a pointer, but a pointer doesn't want a variable, he want the address. And then you've written
`int** bufferArray = testarray.`
You should write
`int* bufferArray = new int [size of array]`    It's for 1D array
and ....

```
int** bufferArray = new int* [rows];
for (size_t = 0 ; i != rows ; ++i){
    bufferArray[i] = new int [colons];
}
```

for 2D array

```
"I cant compile. But shouldnt  int** bufferArray = testarray; just work fine? I mean there is alway an double pointer to the first address of an 2D-Array."
```

And Yes, it will be work nice. If testarray already 2D array

Comment: That dont help. I can do it with dynamic arrays. but I also want to hand over pre-initialised arrays. And as I mentioned in the first post int** bufferArray = testArray; do not work even if its initialised as in the example. Greetings.

Comment: @Lmabda3388 Then you need to change your function. Nothing is going to change the fact that `int[3][4]` cannot be converted to `int**`.